# Get timestamps of a newly created mongo document in mongoose (MERN)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I'm working on a twitter clone to learn MERN stack, here's a new tweet route

```
router.route('/new')
    .post( (req, res) => {

        const { errors, isValid } = validateTweet(req.body);
        
        if (!isValid) {
            return res.status(400).json(errors);
        }
        let tweet = new Tweet({
            content: req.body.content,
            created_by: req.user.id
        })
        User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).json(err)
            
            user.tweets.push(tweet._id);
            user.save();
        });
        tweet.save();

        return res.status(201).json(tweet);
    });
```

Which does not return timestamps for the tweet, how can i achieve this without querying the database for the tweet before returning it?
Here's the model just in case:

```
const tweetSchema = new Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        maxlength: 128,
        trim: true
    },
    created_by: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const Tweet = mongoose.model('Tweet', tweetSchema);
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `new Date()` at the time of insertion?

Comment: Would that come in the same format as mongodb time format? not sure if that would work

Comment: isn't that just a formatting issue? what format were you looking for for the timestamp? ISO? `Date` gives you that, see docs.

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up doing was making the funcion `async` then returning the result of the fulfilled `save()`. Not sure if this is a good practice or not.

```
router.route('/new')
    .post( async (req, res) => {

        const { errors, isValid } = validateTweet(req.body);
        
        if (!isValid) {
            return res.status(400).json(errors);
        }
        let tweet = new Tweet({
            content: req.body.content,
            created_by: req.user.id
        })
        User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).json(err)
            
            user.tweets.push(tweet._id);
            user.save();
        });
        tweet = await tweet.save();

        return res.status(201).json(tweet);
    });
```